# using lines() function on a list of plot

Tags: r

I have a list of plots and i would like to run a linear.fitted lines on each plot in the lists. My attempt is as below:

```
lapply(names(tempmin), function(x) ts.plot(tempmin[[x]],ylab="Minimum Temperature", main = x))
lapply(minlinearfitted, function(x)lines(x,col="green",lwd=2))
```

but i receive an error like below:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I know that this is due to the windows of plot being closed but how can I plot the lines for each plots so I can the analyze the plot from my trend line? my expected results is like below with only one plots:

Expected results:

```
ts.plot(tempmin$Scotland_N[1524:1644],ylab="Minimum Temp")
lines(minlinearfitted$Scotland_N[1524:1644],col="green",lwd=2)
```

the pictures of the plot

[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myvector1=ts(rnorm(6*12, 0, 1), start=c(2013, 1), end=c(2020, 12), 12)
myvector2=ts(rnorm(6*12, 0, 1), start=c(2013, 1), end=c(2020, 12), 12)
library(forecast)
mod1=tslm(myvector1 ~ trend)
mod2=tslm(myvector2 ~ trend)
tempmin=list(ts1=myvector1, ts2=myvector2)
minlinearfitted=list(ts1=mod1, ts2=mod2)
lapply(names(tempmin), function (x) {
  ts.plot(tempmin[[x]], ylab="Minimum temperature", main=x)
  mod=minlinearfitted[[x]]
  abline(a=mod$coef[1]-mod$coef[2]*2013, b=mod$coef[2])
})
```

If the entries in the tmpmin and minlinearfitted have the same names, you can do it in one lapply call. Or if not, you can do this.

```
for (i in 1:length(tempmin)) {
  ts.plot(tempmin[[i]], ylab="Minimum temperature", main=names(tempmin)[i])
  mod=minlinearfitted[[i]]
  abline(a=mod$coef[1]-mod$coef[2]*2013, b=mod$coef[2])
}
```

[image]

[image]